# Phoenix router accepting parameter with forward slash char

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix router with the following structure. The issue is that the param "name" can have a forward slash it in depending on the item such as "ABC/D"

This '/' char gets interpreted as a different route though that does not exist. Is there some way to designate that the forward slash is part of the name and not part of a route?

```
scope "/api", AppWeb do
  scope "/pricing" do
    resources("/inventory", InventoryController, param: "name") do
      get("/quote", InventoryController, :quote, as: :pricing)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has very little to do with [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), that’s HTTP protocol question. To pass any symbol as path/query part in the URL and prevent handlers from treating it as a path and/or controlling symbol, one should [`url-encode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it.

That said, one should encode forward slashes as `%2F` in the path/query parts of URI. The below code shows how it’d be treated by router.

```elixir
#                                                 ⇓⇓
iex||1 ▸ URI.decode("https://google.com/?foo=bar%2Fbaz") 
"https://google.com/?foo=bar/baz"
```